# Is My Proof Correct? (Prove that if $a_i|b_i$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$, then $(a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n)|(b_1 b_2 \cdots b_n)$)

Tags: number-theory

This is from Grimaldi, Exercise 6 from Section 4.3.  I'm posting this question because the book's approach to the proof used mathematical induction, but my approach didn't, and I don't see why we need to use mathematical induction.

Here is the question: Let $n\ in Z^+$ where $ n \geq 2$.  Prove that if $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n,b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n \in Z^+$ and $a_i|b_i$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$, then $(a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n)|(b_1 b_2 \cdots b_n)$. (In case the notation isn't universal, the book defines $b|a$ as meaning "b divides a" and equal to $a = bn$, with $n$ some integer.)

Here is my proof.  Let's choose some arbitrary $n \geq 2$.  That means that $a_i|b_i$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$, which means that $b_i = a_i x_i$, where $x_i$ is the relevant integer.  Thus, $(b_1 b_2 \cdots b_n) = (a_1 x_1 \cdot a_2 x_2 \cdots a_n x_n ) = (a_1a_2 \cdots a_n)(x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n)  $.  Since $(a_1a_2 \cdots a_n)|(a_1a_2 \cdots a_n)(x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n)$, that means that $(a_1a_2 \cdots a_n)|(b_1 b_2 \cdots b_n)$.  Also, since we chose an arbitrary $n\geq2$ at the beginning, it should be true for all $n$ by the rule of universal generalization, and we're done.

Is that a valid proof?  Or am I missing something and we do need to do mathematical induction here?  I apologize if this is rather simple, I just want to make sure I'm not missing an obvious reason for why mathematical induction is required here.

Comment: Looks fine to me. I would use $\prod_{k=1}^n$ rather than "..." but that's just my preference.

Comment: I don't see a problem.  I might prefer induction just because it would make the proof shorter/simpler.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you both!